# Is it okay to ask questions about non-Apple apps for Apple products on Ask Different?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can I ask a question about a non-Apple app that is used on iTouch, iPhone, or iPad on Ask Different?  I know it's a forum about Apple stuff, but I am using the app on an iTouch.  I'm talking about an app like SoundHound, Splashtop, etc. You know, something not made by Apple but used on an Apple product.  If I can't, is there a more appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask on?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to ask on our Apple site, at the very least you should be using the proper name for the Apple product in question: iPod touch.

Comment: And I didn't know there was a site called "Ask Different Meta".  I thought it was just "Meta Stack Overflow".  If you migrated me here, thanks!

Comment: @BigTarantula99: every SE site has their own Meta; SO's doubles for a catch-all for questions about the whole network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for a list of topics you can ask about; third-party software that runs on Apple devices is explicitly included.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info and link.